# How to work with empty array in mongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

i have such shema in MongoDb :

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("57a376dc317843700b7bd83f"),
    "approved" : false,
    "experience" : 0,
    "placeOfWork" : "",
    "education" : "",
    "price" : 0,
    "courses" : [],
    "certificates" : [],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-08-04T17:09:48.773Z"),
    "profileImg" : "images/profile.png",
    "role" : "doctor",
    "phone" : "",
    "password" :'',
    "email" : "ros.pad33alko@gmail.com",
    "foreName" : "",
    "surname" : "",
    "name" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

and i want to store images in array of strings in certificates['image','image'...] but i nee special order, is it posible like in JavaScript to add image to array by index like

```
certificates{index] = 'something';
```

and in mongogoDb it stores like this certificates:[0:'something',1:'something',x:'something'] 0,1,x indexes of array certificates thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You put elements in an array with the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator, elements are added to the end of the array. To insert an element in certain position you can use $push along with the [$position](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position) operator. If the array is empty it does not create null elements. To model the behavior you need, you can add documents to the array like this `{index: 0, image: "something"}`.

By the way, if you are going to store images you may need to have a look at [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) documentation.